# what is a one liner form in python loops?

Tags: python

Here are the instructions:
The for statement following the definition of odds is written in the "long" form for loops. Rewrite it in the concise square-bracket-based "one-liner" form. Use the same temporary variable names, assigning its final value to variable evens. Conclude by printing evens out.

here is the " long form" :

```
odds = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
evens = []
for n in odds:
  evens.append( n + 1 )
print( evens )
```

what would the "one-liner" version of this look like? Thanks everyone

Comment: This probably refers to a list comprehension, which is _not_ a one-line form of a for loop.

Comment: `evens = [n + 1 for n in odds]`

Comment: Did your instructor not give you any resources to answer this yourself?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: These are really bad instructions. I think clearly they reference list-comprehensions, but list comprehensions really are not "one-line for loops". That's a terrible way of describing them.

Comment: thanks. They sucks getting down voted  here. I really am realizing my instructor isn't a code expert. He teaches coding for social science

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> odds = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> print([(n+1) for n in odds])
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

You can read more about list comprehensions here: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python